# Youtube startSeconds and endSeconds on iOS

Tags: ios, video, youtube, youtube-api

I was looking for a way to specify startSeconds and endSeconds to be able to play part of a youtube video in an iOS app, and I came across this :
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube-api-gdata/709DQ0diJEg

Which says that the feature was being looked into by developers about a year ago.

I am not sure if I should file a request or ask here if it is now possible to do so... I tried A LOT of things but never had any success (apart from the startSeconds, but even so, there's often an offset of more than 1 second).

Is there a way of doing this ? My app actually relies on that feature...

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Why dont you comment on that thread so that YouTube api person sees it??

Comment: Well Youtube API people left the Google group to answer only on Stackoverflow as you can see [here](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/09/the-youtube-api-on-stack-overflow.html). Though to my knowledge I've never had an answer from an actual youtube developer... Hoping to see one this time :)